# How many Web worker instances should I prepare?

Tags: html, web-worker

What is the best number of web worker instances I should prepare, if there are 200 independent objects I want to calculate random (x,y) positions for each 1/60 seconds, and there are 8 cores on my computer?

1. 200 instances (because there are 200 independent objects)
2. 8 instances (because there are 8 cores)
3. 7 instances (because there are 7 cores, one used for UI)
4. 1 instance (only single web worker instance works the best?)

How about if there are 400 objects?

Comment: Don't forget this is on the client which might be running on a single core.

Comment: Also consider offloading to a web worker the task of coordination amongst the other ww instead of burdening the main UI with this dolling out and retrieving

Comment: Please share your Findings @izumi

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to test the 4 cases you've suggested, timing how long your operations take, and see how the user interface feels while the tests are running, and see.

You could even use something like http://wg.oftn.org/projects/core-estimator/demo/ in your app to attempt to determine the number of cores dynamically in the app itself.

I suspect you'll get either [number of cores] or [number of cores - 1] as the best values. You could then post back an answer (that is better than this one :-) here with your results.